# Do contractions with Hebrew prepositions occur later in the textual history? Cf. Ex 3:14-15

Tags: hebrew, linguistics

I'm doing an exegesis of Exodus 3, and I notice that v. 14 and v. 15 repeat a clause, except that v. 14 contracts a preposition within that clause.

3:14 כֹּ֤ה תֹאמַר֙ לִבְנֵ֣י יִשְׂרָאֵ֔ל

3:15 כֹּה־תֹאמַר֘ אֶל־בְּנֵ֣י יִשְׂרָאֵל

v. 14 is sometimes interpreted as a later addition. I'd like to know if there's any reason to treat the contraction in 3:14 as further evidence that it's a later addition.

Thank you.

Comment: תאמר לבני ישראל is not necessarily a contraction of תאמר אל בני ישראל. The two formulations has slightly different meanings. The תאמר אל formulation has the nuance of an strong imperative whereas the תאמר ל formulation is softer. It is a difference similar to that between "tell them" and "say to them".

Comment: I think it is a real contraction, instead. If we find in the same verse two term variants - with no basis to infer some sub-meanings - we have to conclude scribal changes intervened. In Gen 1:6 we find the variant הַמָּיִם along with לָמָיִם. Do the different prefixes indicate a different meaning of this noun (waters)? No. The Gesenius' Hebrew Grammar affirms that "the original form of the Hebrew article is generally considered to have been [EL]" [§35l]. This being the case, the 2 cited variants were 2 contractions of the 'original' term, sourced by 2 different scribes (scribes' family).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In all probability, the original Hebrew terms were complete (that is, not contracted).

The essence of the problem revolves around the fact the MT are redrafted texts. Granted, the context (and a number of other factors) permits us to grasp the concepts of the TaNaKh topics. But, we have to maintain the fact that the MT wording - often, very often - are not the original wording.

Benjamin Kennicott rightly sustained:

> It may now assumed on an allowed Maxim – that the Hebrew Scriptures have not reached us in that pure and perfect state, in which they were originally written – That they have undergone indeed many great and grievous corruptions, occasioned by the ignorance or negligence of transcribers.
>   -- *Critica Sacra; or, a Short Introduction to Hebrew Criticism*, London, 1774; p. 5

Your  example (on Exo 3:14, 15) is only one of the many many anomalies we found in MT. Another couple of examples can be:

- the term (noun) we often translate ‘luminaries’ (Gen 1:14-16). In verse 14 we find מְאֹרֹת; in verse 15 we find מְאוֹרֹת ; in verse 16 מְּאֹרֹת, again (‘enjoy’ yourself to discover these variants into this microcontext!);
- the term (noun) we often translate ‘waters’ in Gen 1:6. There we find it in the articulate variants הַמָּיִם but also לָמָיִם, both in this very verse!

As things are, we may conclude that the scribes did not modify the TaNaKh texts with the aim to distort them. More probably they operated such changes to adapt those texts to the style/manner of the epoch the scribes lived. This view would explain why:

1. they did eliminate the entire linguistic structure linked with the original use of Cases;
2. they did eliminate the chronological factors (tenses) that were originally implemented into the Hebrew verbal forms; and
3. they transformed the normal/logical prepositional use of the waw (like a simple conjunction) in a polysemous (and, then, pleonastic) term.

In brief, you ask if ‘there’s any reason to treat the contraction on 3:14 as further evidence that it’s a later addition’. The answer is ‘No’, because into the Masoretic Texts the more ancient (not contracted) term variants are sometimes **mingled with** (that is, they are present in the same context) the subsequent variants (contracted).

Comment: The assumption that there ever was an "original wording" or "pure and perfect state in which they were originally written" is unproven conjecture that later generations have imposed on the subject. There is no evidence of any such "original version" for any books in the OT. The very idea of "a single original version" is counter to the nature of Israelite and Jewish culture and history.

Comment: Even if we disagree with the concept of 'original wording', we have to admit primitive nouns' form existed. On the basis of one of the example I mentioned, it is logical to conclude that one between the forms מְאֹרֹת -  מְאוֹרֹת - must be a previous wording. So, the other form was neologized in a subsequent period (I think the longer form was the more ancient one). I cited Kennicott mainly to back the fact the scribes operated changes in the TaNaKh wording.

Comment: There is no reason to assume that one was earlier than the other. The two different spellings could be parallel writing traditions. You need to be able to clearly disprove this hypothesis. On the other hand, there is plenty of evidence that the addition of the *umot hakriah*, in this case the *holam* in מאורות, was in fact a later innovation and that the *ctiv haser* form was the earlier, consonant-only form.

Comment: I think otherwise, because I don't believe the waw added in מְאוֹרֹת was only an _epenthetic_, or intrusive letter. I think this letter, there, marks an ancient form of participle (perhaps, present), which on it were based (along with the past participle form) the entire structure of the nouns. Let the readers decide for themselves. So, the omission of this mark (waw) denotes a posterior situation, when a scribe (or, scribes' family) did not understand longer the meaning of this transforming particle.

Comment: The *waw* in מאורות us not epenthetic, it does not change pronunciation, it only aids in reading. It is a mater lectionis. The consensus of scholarly opinion on of how the אמות הקריה developed over history is consistent with this article https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%91_%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9D . Your view is outside that consensus, and therefore a difficult position to justify.

Comment: Sorry, we are part of two different school of thought. You are part, evidently, to the school of 'only-consonantist' (in reference to the alphabetic Hebrew graphemes)

Comment: I belong to the older school of 'holographemists', like Josephus, Origen, Jerome, Roger Bacon, and many others, who believe the Hebrew alphabet included consonants, along with really vowels, not merely polivalent matres lectionis. Like you see, we are of opposite viewpoints.